# Grails Application Create Error In Netbeans

Tags: grails, netbeans, groovy

I Cant able to create Grails Application In Netbeans IDE, My IDE show me to create new Grails Application and when i click create Button It Shows Error In Console.

JAVA VERSION : 1.6
GRAILS VERSION : 2.3.7
IDE : NetBeans

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:235)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:263)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:235)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:263)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jline/console/completer/CompletionHandler
       at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:129)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jline.console.completer.CompletionHandler
      at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:175)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:147)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsRootLoader.loadClass(GrailsRootLoader.java:51)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 13 more

Comment: Java 1.6?!?!?!?

Answer (score 2):

First I would recommend checking your Java version.

Although the minimum requirements for Grails framework 2.3.7 is java 1.6 as you can see in the [Grails introduction web site](http://docs.grails.org/2.3.x/guide/introduction.html#whatsNew23):

Here is the main paragraph describes it:

> Before installing Grails you will need as a minimum a Java Development
>   Kit (JDK) installed version 1.6 or above. Download the appropriate JDK
>   for your operating system, run the installer, and then set up an
>   environment variable called JAVA_HOME pointing to the location of this
>   installation.

I would suggest using more advance version of JAVA such as 1.7 or 1.8. Especially the 1.8 which offers vast majority of changes and improvements from the older JAVA versions.

Another thing that should be checked is your JAVA_HOME (Environment variable) value. Are you sure it points to the relevant JAVA JDK ? if not that can be a good reason to the error you have.

Personally I am using **Intellij IDEA** (JetBrains IDE) and it works great with the **Grails** Framework using the **Gradle** building tool.